# How To Add a Tiled Map To Your Python

Tags: python, tmx

I was trying to ad a TMX file to my python file but an error occurred: No such file or directory: 'F:\myProg\Python\Pygame\unnamed.png

```
import pyglet
import pygame
from pytmx import load_pygame
import pytmx
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,500))

     
bg = pytmx.load_pygame("F:\myProg\Python\Pygame\TIle.tmx")



while(True):
                                    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if(event.type == pygame.QUIT):
            quit()

    for layer in bg.visible_layers:
            for x, y, gid, in layer:
                tile = bg.get_tile_image_by_gid(gid)
                
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Does the file actually exist? Also, the error you have there doesn't seem to be anywhere in your code. Please include the full traceback of the error in the question.

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
"F:\myProg\Python\Pygame\TIle.tmx"
```

to

```
"F:\\myProg\\Python\\Pygame\\TIle.tmx"
```

Comment: Nothing Changed The Error Occurred